# In JNI, setting and getting elements from jobjectArray

Tags: android, java-native-interface

```
jstring ret_str = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, output);
(*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,result,1,ret_str);

jint bit_count = 5;
(*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env,result,0,(jobject)bit_count);
```

The last line gives an error FATAL ERROR.

Here `output` is `char*` and `result` is `jobjectArray`.

All I need is to add strings,ints,floats etc... to jobjectArray and want to return the jobjectArray.

When am adding jstring their's no error but for other primitive type its throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast jint to jobject like you would in Java.  C has no idea how to promote that data type.  You will need to find the java.lang.Integer class in JNI and construct it with the jint argument to get a Integer jobject.

Here is some code, go back and review the documentation and preform the needed error checking.

```
jclass Integer_class = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Integer");
jmethodID = Integer_init = (*env)->GetMethodID(
                env,
                Integer_class,
                "<init>",
                "(I)V");
Integer_object = (*env)->NewObject(
                env,
                Integer_class,
                Integer_init,
                bit_count);
```